# duplicate key in table for foreign key in sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, foreign-key-relationship

I am using `mysql_workbench` to create database I have `products_types`, `categories` and `subcategories` table. `category_id` and `subcategory_id` are the foreign keys referencing to `categories` and `subcategories` table respectively. When when I `forward engineer` this model from `workbench` to `mysql database on phpMyAdmin` it gives error as

```
Can't write; duplicate key in table 'product_types'
```

This is the exact code along with error.

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1022: Can't write; duplicate key in table 'product_types'
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `argo_project_01_2`.`product_types`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `argo_project_01_2`.`product_types` (
          `id` INT NOT NULL,
          `category_id` INT NULL,
          `subcategory_id` INT NULL,
          `title` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
          `description` TEXT NULL,
          `status` INT NULL DEFAULT 0,
          `created` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
          `modified` TIMESTAMP NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
          INDEX `category_id_idx` (`category_id` ASC),
          INDEX `subcategory_id_idx` (`subcategory_id` ASC),
          CONSTRAINT `category_id`
            FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`)
            REFERENCES `argo_project_01_2`.`categories` (`id`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `subcategory_id`
            FOREIGN KEY (`subcategory_id`)
            REFERENCES `argo_project_01_2`.`subcategories` (`id`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 9 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

What is wrong in the query ?

Comment: Is this all you're doing? It blows up before you try to even add data? And you don't already have a table named product_types?

Comment: No I have no `product_types` tables but `categories` and `subcategories` exist

Comment: have you tried renaming the contraints(both) different from foreign key.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may be solved by Changing constraint names "category_id" and "subcategory_id" to for example "fk_category_id" and "fk_subcategory_id".

Edit : 
Also you can remove "category_id_idx" and "subcategory_id_idx" indexes because the foreign key automatically generates an index.

Comment: what is the use of `constraint names` ?

Comment: @AnujTBE when you create a foreign key constraint you can specify a name for that. Change that name to a different value against the column name